# Computed Object V-Model Is Not Updating After Change

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

In my form, I allow users to set different languages for each field. I am using a computed property that is used for the v-model. When changing the language, my text field does not get cleared.

Here is an example of what I'm talking about: https://jsfiddle.net/eonq472a/

```
var vm = new Vue({
    el: "#app",
  computed: {
    dataObject() {
      return {
        first_name: {
          en: '',
          es: ''
        }
      }
    }
  },
  data: {
    language: 'en',
    languageItems: [
        {
        text: 'English',
        value: 'en'
      },
      {
        text: 'Spanish',
        value: 'es'
      }
    ]
  }
});
```

Try typing something into the text field while the language is English, then change the language to Spanish. The old English text will remain. The only way to get the text to clear is to change the language multiple times.

Note: I am using a computed property because in my actual code, I am relying on 3 ajax calls to get my data to create the computed object.

Comment: see below edit :key is what you are missing

Answer (score 3):

*Edit - re-read your question and looked at the fiddle again. You question has nothing to do with v-model or computed.

You need to add :key="language" to your name component. Vue doe not know it needs to re-render that component because it won't watch the language variable by default. By adding key you tell it when that variable change to re-render which then moves your [language] call to the alternate language.

```
<v-text-field v-model="dataObject.first_name[language]" label="First name" :key="language"></v-text-field>
```

---

Computed is used to do some calculations on data and **return** the result after the calculations/manipulation/modification. It does not actually store the data as a stand alone item. Typically this would be used along with a Vuex store or similar where the data is stores elsewhere and you don't want to have to type `this.$store.state.module.name` everywhere.This would allow you to get and set the long-form version and locally just use `name`

I have made a basic fiddle that will show how to use a computed value in v-model but you can see that the computed property is setting and retiriving a seperatly stored variable in order to work.

https://jsfiddle.net/goofballtech/s3xkzh2f/7/

```
<div id="app">
  <input type="text" v-model="name">
  {{name}}
</div>

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    nameStore: ''
  },
  computed: {
    name: {
      get() {
        return this.nameStore
      },
      set(value) {
        this.nameStore = value
      },
    },
  },
  methods: {}
})
```

You can see there is a getter and a setter in the computed value. One updates the placeholder variable and the other retrieves the placeholders value then returns it to the location where the variable has been called.

Comment: Wow, i didn't know that you can use a getter and setter in a computed property

Answer (score 2):

For me it looks like you are trying to use a computet property as a v-model and in my opinion that is not possible. The first_name object must be in the data section.

```
var vm = new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    data() {
      return {
        language: 'en',
        first_name: {
          en: '',
          es: ''
        },
        languageItems: [
          {
            text: 'English',
            value: 'en'
          },
          {
            text: 'Spanish',
            value: 'es'
          }
        ]
      }
    }
 });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/5w9n8j13/

if you now enter a value and change the language, it will be saved under the selected language.